# Why is GCloud CLI command failing with "Project ID not found."

Tags: gcloud, gcloud-cli

### This error

`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Users instance [sXXXXXXX@sty-holdings.com] not found: Project ID not found.`
and its sometimes reports the error this way:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) HttpError accessing <https://oslogin.googleapis.com/v1/users/scott.yacko@sty-holdings.com/loginProfile?alt=json&projectId=savup-production>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Tue, 25 Jul 2023 19:02:40 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': 500}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

is returned from this command
`gcloud compute ssh --zone "${GC_REGION}" "${GC_REMOTE_LOGIN}" --command "if [ ! -f \"/etc/original.fstab\" ]; then lsblk --noheadings --raw -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk 'length(\$1) == 3 && \$1 != \"sda\"' > /tmp/drive-letter.tmp; fi";`

which is the first command issued after the instance is built.

This same script has been run in a development project without any errors.

Instance command:

```
gcloud compute instances create savup-prod-0001
    --zone=us-central1-c
    --machine-type=e2-small
    --network-interface=network-tier=PREMIUM,subnet=default,address=34.67.100.152
    --metadata=environment=,enable-oslogin=true
    --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE
    --provisioning-model=STANDARD
    --service-account=838247644754-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
    --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
    --tags=nats,savup-http,savup-https,plaid
    --no-shielded-secure-boot
    --no-restart-on-failure
    --create-disk=auto-delete=yes,boot=yes,device-name=,image=projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-2004-focal-v20230724,mode=rw
    --shielded-vtpm
    --shielded-integrity-monitoring
    --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE
    --reservation-affinity=any
    --key-revocation-action-type=stop
    --create-disk=device-name=savup-prod-0001-nats,mode=rw,name=savup-prod-0001-nats
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/savup-production/zones/us-central1-c/instances/savup-prod-0001].
NAME             ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
savup-prod-0001  us-central1-c  e2-small                   10.128.0.43  34.67.100.152  RUNNING
```

The project id is set before the instance is created with this command:
`gcloud config set project XXXXXXXXX`

***NOTE: This is a production level project***

### What I've done so far

- Rerun this in a ***non-production*** project and it works.
- Checked the gCloud CLI version which is `--version 438.0.0`
- Changed the OS image to `projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-2004-focal-v20230724`
- Rerun this again in a ***non-production*** project and it works.

Answer (score 0):

### The Solution

I had to update the gCloud CLI to version `440.0.0` and move to the most recent OS image. Upgrading the gCloud CLI alone didn't work.

All I can say, is there is a bug and the error message needs to be improved to point someone in the right direction.